# Trying to make a button change the web view url but when I press it it crashes the app

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

So I am trying to make an app in Xcode 8 basically I have a webview and a side bar with buttons I want to make those buttons change the webview but for some reason when I press them the app crashes.

This is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var menuView: UIView!
        @IBOutlet weak var leadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

        var menuShowing = false

        @IBOutlet weak var Webview: UIWebView!

            override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            menuView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
            menuView.layer.shadowRadius = 6

            let url = URL(string: "http://www.peulibrary.com/application/")
            Webview.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))

}
    @IBAction func loadSecond(_ sender: Any) {

                let url = URL(string: "http://www.peulibrary.com/application/category/פעולות-גן-ג/")
                Webview.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
}
```

when I run the app in the simulator I get an error at the second

```
Webview.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
```

that says "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

any help appreciated, thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `URL` contains special characters so encode your URL string then use it with `webView`.

```
let stringURL = "http://www.peulibrary.com/application/category/פעולות-גן-ג/"
if let encodeURL = stringURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed),
   let url = URL(string: encodeURL) {

      Webview.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
}
```

Comment: Wow ... You so faster

Comment: @NazmulHasan Thanks mate :)